# Razor page can't see referenced class library at run time in ASP.NET Core RC2

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I started a new MVC Web Application project for the RC2 release and I'm trying to add a class library as a project reference.

I added a simple class library to my project and referenced it and got the following in the project.json file:

```
"frameworks": {
  "net452": {
    "dependencies": {
      "MyClassLibrary": {
        "target": "project"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

I can use this library in any of the Controllers and the Startup.cs files without any trouble but I get the following error at run time when I try and use the library from a Razor page:

> The name 'MyClassLibrary' does not exist in the current context
>   Output.WriteLine(MyClassLibrary.MyStaticClass.SomeStaticString);

It's weird because I'm getting intellisense for the class library when I'm editing the Razor page, and I can't find anything that says you can't use project references from here.

I thought it was hard enough getting this running under RC1 with the "wrap folder" in the class library project but this has me stumped.

Comment: Have you set the preserveCompilationContext flag? ie https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/c392363791b3e67918f01c77f4833d20a5453309/samples/Mvc.TagHelperSample.Web/project.json#L5

Comment: To get around this, I've wrapped the required functionality in a class within the web project, which the view can reference without issue. I wait with baited breath for an actual answer/fix for this one.

Comment: The issue is tracked here:
https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/755

Comment: @N.TaylorMullen Yep, this was on by default when I created the new project.

Comment: @N.TaylorMullen setting that flag worked for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A workaround has been posted on the issue page (cred to pranavkm and patrikwlund)
https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/755

Apparently you need to explicitly add references to Razor compilation using RazorViewEngineOptions.CompilationCallback.

Add the following to your ConfigureServices method in your Startup class:

```
var myAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select(x => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(x.Location)).ToList();

services.Configure((RazorViewEngineOptions options) =>
{
    var previous = options.CompilationCallback;
    options.CompilationCallback = (context) =>
    {
        previous?.Invoke(context);

        context.Compilation = context.Compilation.AddReferences(myAssemblies);
    };
});
```

Comment: Disclaimer: GetAssemblies() does not guarantee a complete list, since it only returns already loaded assemblies. So test it to ensure it resolves all your references correctly.

Comment: This works! I had to explicitly create an object from the ClassLibrary before calling GetAssemblies() to insure it was in the list first though.

Comment: @Matt if you want to be explicit about which csproj-assemblies to include you can use the following snippet to resolve them one at a time: `typeof(MyStaticClass).Assembly`. You also won't have to pre-load the assembly.

Comment: net core doesn't contain the AppDomain class any more

Answer (score 5):

I had to filter out dynamic assemblies to avoid this runtime exception:
*The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.*

This worked for me:

```
var myAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .Where(x => !x.IsDynamic)
    .Select(x => Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(x.Location))
    .ToList();
services.Configure((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngineOptions options) => {
     var previous = options.CompilationCallback;
     options.CompilationCallback = (context) => {
         previous?.Invoke(context);
         context.Compilation = context.Compilation.AddReferences(myAssemblies);
     };
});
```