# ASP.NET Core RC2 migration - Error while loading views

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, assemblies

So I did the update to RC2, it took me a while but I got most things solved. Currently I have one issue that I haven't found a solution for.

When my view gets called I immediately get this kind of error in the browser (nothing server side):

The type 'RefreshableJob' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'HeuristicLab.Clients.Hive-3.3, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ba48961d6f65dcec'.
        @if (Model.userJobs.Count == 0)

This happens on all my views where I try to load some data and it worked perfectly before the update. Here are the dependencies I use in my project.json

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final", 
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server": "0.1.0-rc2-20896",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"AngularJS.Intellisense": "1.0.3",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"HeuristicALGAuto": "1.0.0"
```

},

```
 "frameworks": {

    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
        "HeuristicLab.Algorithms.ALPS-3.3": "1.0.0-*",
        ......
```

here is an example of a view file:

```
using HeuristicLab.Clients.Hive.WebJobManager.ViewModels

@model JobViewModel

<!-- Displays the job manager overview -->

<div id="userId" style="display:none">@ViewBag.SessionId</div>
<div>
    <!-- Main nav menu-->
    @Html.Partial("Navbar", new NavbarViewModel("Job", Model.currentUser))

    <!-- Job menu-->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li role="presentation"
            class="active">
            <a asp-controller="Job"
               asp-action="Index">
                <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Jobs
            </a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"
            class="">
            <a asp-controller="Job"
               asp-action="Uploads">
                <i class="fa fa-cloud"></i>  Uploads
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    @Html.Partial("_ErrorMessage", Model.message)

    <div class="row"
         style="padding:10px; margin-right:0!important">
        @if (Model.userJobs.Count == 0)
            {
            <div>
                <p style="text-align:center">
                    No jobs found
                </p>
            </div>

        }
```

I can confirm that the data gets loaded through the controller perfectly, this only happens on the return View(...); call. I tried debugging into the view itself to see what's going on but the debugger never enters the view itself, error just gets thrown.

Any idea is appreciated, I really have no clue where to begin for this. I can also provide extra information if necessary. 
Thanks

Comment: I also stumbled across same error, will wait for an answer here since you already asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution in another thread: [Razor page can't see referenced class library at run time in ASP.NET Core RC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289436/razor-page-cant-see-referenced-class-library-at-run-time-in-asp-net-core-rc2?rq=1)
Copy/paste and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me with minor modification, needed to filter out few assemblies: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(x => !x.IsDynamic && x.Location != "")`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be fixed now in final aspnet core 1.0 version