# Reference a NET461 DLL model type from ASP.NET Core View

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2

I have a new ASP.NET Core RC2 built as follows:

- Model stored in DLL library of .NET Framework 461
- Web is MVC Core 1.0 Full Framework - not based on core framework

when reference the model type in the DLL library and run the project, i got the following error:

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to
>   process this request. Please review the following specific error
>   details and modify your source code appropriately. Generated Code The
>   type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace
>   'ADMA.EWRS' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   23.    public class _Views_Murad_Index_cshtml : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage>
>   The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace
>   'ADMA.EWRS' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   39.        public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper>
>   Html { get; private set; } An error occurred during the compilation of
>   a resource required to process this request. Please review the
>   following specific error details and modify your source code
>   appropriately. Generated Code The type or namespace name 'Data' does
>   not exist in the namespace 'ADMA.EWRS' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)
>   23.    public class _Views_Murad_Index_cshtml : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage>
>   The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace
>   'ADMA.EWRS' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   39.        public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper>
>   Html { get; private set; }

Config Project.json as follow :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "ADMA.EWRS.Web.Security": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "dependencies": {
        "ADMA.EWRS.BizDomain": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "ADMA.EWRS.Data.Models": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },


  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZIwG.png)

[X Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhKlo.png)

Comment: Does your xproj file have a ProjectReference entry for ADMA.EWRS.Data.Models project?

Comment: Yes please check attached image 2

Comment: I meant, if you open ADMA.EWRS.Web.Core.xproj in Notepad, do you see  a ProjectReference entry for ADMA.EWRS.Data.Models project? If it's missing, then that may be the problem.

Comment: It is ther, the reference is there  :  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ADMA.EWRS.BizDomain\ADMA.EWRS.BizDomain.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ADMA.EWRS.Data.Models\ADMA.EWRS.Data.Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: It may be related to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289436/razor-page-cant-see-referenced-class-library-at-run-time-in-asp-net-core-rc2?rq=1

Comment: thank you it works

Comment: Please use the proper tags in future! When your quesiton is related to ASP.NET Core use "asp.net-core" tag ! NOT "asp.net" and "core", both are completely unrelated to your question. Please read the tag descriptions before adding them

Comment: It is typo @Tseng I am new to stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved after Adding Razor Options as in below code :

```
 services.AddMvc().// Murad Add this for RC2, remove it if release 1.0 after June 
                AddRazorOptions(options =>
            {
                var previous = options.CompilationCallback;
                options.CompilationCallback = context =>
                {
                    previous?.Invoke(context);
                    context.Compilation = context.Compilation.AddReferences(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(ADMA.EWRS.Data.Models.Murad).Assembly.Location));
                };
            });

            //var myAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select(x => Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(x.Location)).ToList();
            //services.Configure((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngineOptions options) =>
            //{
            //    var previous = options.CompilationCallback;
            //    options.CompilationCallback = (context) =>
            //    {
            //        previous?.Invoke(context);

            //        context.Compilation = context.Compilation.AddReferences(myAssemblies);
            //    };
            //});
```

Check

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4686